# Making both 'insert bytes' and 'remove bytes' to work via 'insert bytes' with positive/negative offsets

Tags: c

I have two operations that are basically same:

```
insert_bytes(from, count)
delete_bytes(start, stop) -> delete_bytes(from, count)
```

insert_bytes implementation sample:

```
unsigned char* new_bytes = (unsigned char*)malloc((old_length+count)*sizeof(unsigned char));
memcpy(new_bytes, old_bytes, from); // negative value can't go to from here
memcpy(new_bytes+count, old_bytes+from, old_length-from); 
return new_bytes+from; // pointer to write
```

is there any safe way to implement delete_bytes as a call to insert_bytes (with negative offsets) without writing 5-6 lines of positive/negative value checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No...  your delete function doesn't know how much was malloc'ed earlier.

- If you made a C++ (this is tagged as C) class you could encapsulate what the current size is.
- You could make a function:  resize(from, current_size, delta) which would work.

Comment: current_size is available from outside, and plan to use in C++ too.. ok, thanks for reminding this stuff.. feeling more clear :)